What happens if we use Pvu2 to insert a gene in the rop of pBR322
My book shows that pBR322 has a Pvu II site in the rop, I know that rop codes for proteins required for replication of the plasmid, so what happens if we use the Pvu II Restriction Enzyme and insert a foreign gene there.
Will the replication stop?
If yes, the what is the significance of having a site at such an essential position.

I think that inserting Pvu 2 might reduce the rate of duplication of the plasmid.

Have a look where the PvuI is sited - what is that region used for, and why might this be important for your cloning.

I couldn't get what you mean to say...

Sorry, misread PvuII as PvuI. The comment applies still - what would happen to the plasmid if you insert a DNA segment into the PvuII site? Would that region look the same and do the same function?  As to why there's a site there - because that's the cut sequence for that restriction enzyme and it just so happens to lie there.

Yes, insertion of foreign gene at this site would disrupt the process of replication as rop protein is essential for the replication of the plasmid.
The significance of having a site at such a position is that it would help the researchers to control and manipulate the plasmid. It would be helpful to study gene function as well as its regulation.
